# The memory necessary to store a matrix within the scope of an IF command is allocated only inside this scope?

Tags: c, memory

Let us consider this piece of code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100
int main()
{
    int n;

    scanf("%d",&n);

    if(n>0){
        int m[N ][N] = {0};
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to understand the behavior of this code regarding the memory. I would like to answer to following questions:

1. The memory necessary to store the matrix m will be allocated only
       if n > 0? Or is it allocated at the begining of the programa, in an
       independent way?
2. The memory necessary to allocate the matrix m
           will be released at the end of the scope of the if?

Answer (score 3):

As @dbush says, code can only legally access the memory named `m` while  inside the scope of the `if` block.

Where the allocation is actually done will depend on the compiler and optimizer settings.

With no optimization, both gcc and clang do adjust the stack pointer (allocating memory) at the entry to main, but perform the initialization to zero only if `n` is non-zero.

With -O3 optimization, they both only call `scanf` and return 0, since those are the only observable effects.  Neither compiler actually sets aside memory or looks at the value scanned, or attempts initialization.

Evidence:  https://godbolt.org/z/6WRhxz

Answer (score 1):

The memory used by `m` is only valid within the scope of the `if` block.  So if you were to save a pointer to it outside of the block you would invoke undefined behavior if you tried to dereference that pointer outside the block.

That being said, an implementation may choose to set aside stack space for all local variables regardless of scope when a function is entered.  For example, if I take your code and change `N` to 2000 the application immediately core dumps as soon as it starts, which indicates that it attempts to allocate space on the stack for an object that is too large.